# Why does my program exit immediately after playing a gloss animation?

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am learning how to use the Gloss library to make some animations in Haskell.

Consider the code below which animates a circle that shrinks and expands its radius with time.

```
import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game

type Radius = Float
type RealTime   = Float

data World = World Radius RealTime

main :: IO ()
main
 = do   let initWorld = World 100.0 0
        let windowSize = (800,800)
        let windowPosition = (200,200)
        putStrLn "Before play"
        play (InWindow "Wobbling Circle" windowSize windowPosition)
              white 40 initWorld renderWorld handleEvent stepWorld
        putStrLn "After play"

renderWorld :: World -> Picture
renderWorld (World rad rtime ) = Pictures [ Circle rad ]

handleEvent :: Event -> World -> World
handleEvent _ = id

stepWorld ::  Float -> World -> World -- wobbling circle
stepWorld  _ (World _ rtime)  = World (100 * sin rtime) (rtime+0.1)
```

I compiled this code with `ghc --make -O2 -threaded Main.hs` on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

When I run the code, the "Before play" statement is printed out and then the animation starts as expected. However, when I close the animation window, the code terminates immediately **without** printing the "After Play" statement. Why is that?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but I have some dependency issues which cause `play` to produce what appears to be an exception (`tmp: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)`), so perhaps closing the window also causes an unhandled exception?

Comment: Looks like a buffering problem. Try to flush stout before exiting `hFlush stdout`

Comment: @mb14 I still get the same problem :-(

Comment: Tested in Windows 10 : on closing, ghci tells `freeglut (<interactive>): fghInitialize: CreateDC failed, Screen size info may be incorrect
This is quite likely caused by a bad '-display' parameter` and then crashes, even with an exception handler around `play`.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are using the GLUT backend (the default). Take a look at some of the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.10.2.3/src/Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/GLUT.hs) for `gloss` (exactly as it appears with comments):

```
instance Backend GLUTState where
        initBackendState           = glutStateInit
        initializeBackend          = initializeGLUT

        -- non-freeglut doesn't like this: (\_ -> GLUT.leaveMainLoop)
        exitBackend                = (\_ -> System.exitWith System.ExitSuccess)

....
```

When it exits the main loop, `gloss` will call `exitBackend`, whatever it is. For GLUT, that simply calls `System.exitWith` which naturally will terminate your program. The more sensible thing to do would be to call `leaveMainLoop` but as the comment in the code says, implementations of `glut` other than `freeglut` don't work well with that function (why? who knows. This is what the authors of gloss claim).

Your potential solutions are to use `freeglut` specifically and modify the source code of `gloss` to change `exitBackend`; or use the GLFW backend, which doesn't have this problem.